# Relationship between R^2 and sum of squared errors in non-linear models

Tags: nonlinear-regression, r-squared

I'm reading from different sources ([whuber's answer on R^2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous/13317#13317), [another source](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression)) that when using R^2 one needs to be careful with regard to interpretation - both in linear and non-linear models.

In linear models R^2 makes sense, because one has the relationship $S_\text{tot}=S_\text{reg}+S_\text{error}$, but in non-linear regression this relationship is no longer valid. I wonder - why is this relationship no longer valid in non-linear regression? Is there an intuitive explanation for this, or is it purely mathematical?

Reading from [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-July/023461.html) discussion, I quote:

> *"There is a good reason that an nls model fit in R does not provide r-squared - r-squared doesn't make sense for a general nls model.*
>
> *One way of thinking of r-squared is as a comparison of the residual sum of squares for the fitted model to the residual sum of squares for
>   a trivial model that consists of a constant only.*  **You cannot
>   guarantee that this is a comparison of nested models when dealing with
>   an nls model.  If the models aren't nested this comparison is not
>   terribly meaningful**."

Can one not have a non-linear nested model, such that this comparison *is* meaningful? Is there any case in non-linear regression where R^2 will be meaningful?

Answer (score 2):

I completely disagree that $R^2$ lacks meaning in nonlinear models.

When you minimize square loss, whether the model is linear or not, you are estimating conditional means. What better baseline that you *must* beat to have a model worth anything than predicting the conditional means all to be the overall mean? If all of your fancy modeling still gets outperformed by predicting `AVERAGE(A:A)` (to use some Excel terminology) every time, I think it's safe to say that your modeling is quite poor.

If you take $R^2$ to be the following, that's exactly what you are doing.

$$
1-\dfrac{
\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i - \hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i - \bar y
\right)^2
}
$$

If the numerator of the fraction is smaller than the denominator, equivalent to having a positive $R^2$ value, then you've at least made some improvement over the bare minimum baseline. If the numerator of the fraction is larger than the denominator, equivalent to having a negative $R^2$ value, then the baseline model outperforms your model.

Nested models have some nice properties when you want to do parameter inference, but for assessing your predictions with the above $R^2$ formula, I see no reason to require that.

I find this perspective on $R^2$ to be elegant, as it relates to ways of comparing other types of models (["classification"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/563941/247274) through McFadden's $R^2$, [quantile regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/580261/247274)) and even to ["chunk testing"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27429/247274), such as ANOVA and similar partial F-tests.

[For an out-of-sample $R^2$-type of performance measure, I have a strong opinion.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/590199/247274)

[For why nonlinear regression $R^2$ lacks the usual "proportion of variance explained" interpretation, I posted a question and self-answer about a year ago to address this very issue.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/551916/247274)