# Dropping the non-significant parameters in multiple regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

Given the standard multiple linear regression model
$$Y=X\beta+\epsilon\sim N(X\beta,\; \sigma^2I)$$
One derives the distribution for the estimated parameters
$$\hat{\beta}\sim N(\beta,\; (X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2)$$
Then for deciding if $\hat{\beta}_j$ contributes significantly to the model, one forms the test statistic
$$t_j=\frac{\hat{\beta}_j-0}{s\sqrt{v_j}}$$
where $v_j$ is the $j^{th}$ diagonal element of $(X^TX)^{-1}$ and $s$ is the sample standard deviation.

Now suppose we want to test to see if multiple parameters together are superfluous, it seems like the standard method is to use an F-test, but why don't we instead set $\beta=\hat{\beta}$ except we zero-out those elements of $\beta$ we want to test for (call it $\beta^*$) and then form the test statistic
$$P^{-1}(\hat{\beta}-\beta^*)$$
where $P^TP=(X^TX)^{-1}s^2$ is the factorization we know exists since the covariance matrix is positive-definite.  If $s^2=\sigma^2$ (the variance is known), then this statistic is a standard multivariate normal under the assumption that $\beta=\beta^*$.

Thus if the variance has to be estimated, then assuming we know its distribution, which maybe we don't, we should be able to form a p-test.  So I guess my question is, is this a valid test?  Can we find this distribution if all we have is the sample variance?

Comment: If you can find the distribution in the t-test (with unknown sample variance) ... then you should be able to find the distribution for the F-test :)

Comment: @Stat is what I described the F-test?  I thought the F-test was something different.

Comment: In regression, you can do almost all test of hypothesis using the F-testor or better to say partial F-test. You can do the t-test, or $H_0: B_0=B_1=...=B_p=0$ vs not $H_0$ or $H_0: B_1=3B_2$  vs not $H_0$. Basically any linear combinations can be done by F-test.

Answer (score 1):

What you aim to do is a [chunk test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests). This is minimally different in spirit from the usual t-test or F-test of a single coefficient. However, instead of comparing nested models where the smaller model just drops one coefficient, the smaller model drops several. This can go to the extreme of dropping all coefficients except the intercept. This is the “overall” F-test that often gets reported in software summaries of regression models.

However, keep in mind that fitting a model, dropping features with insignificant coefficients (or an insignificant chunk), and fitting a new model on the remaining features distorts all of your downstream inferences. This relates to points 1, 2, 3, 4, and 7 [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/).