# Comparing two logistic regressions

Tags: r, logistic, multiple-regression

I am working on creating a predictive model using logistic regressions. I am hoping to compare two different populations, using the same set of variables but different data sets with different sample sizes. Is there a good way to compare the two regressions in R to see if they are statistically different from each other?

Edit for clarification: My goal is to determine if the variables affect the outcome differently to a statistical degree. My analysis is about political socialization of two different populations, so I want to try to determine if xx population is socialized differently than yy population to a statistically significant degree. The two logistic models look different, but I am trying to give a more analytical answer than just "they look different".

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding your objective ? You want to estimate a model on a sample and look at the performance on another one (in that case, this is basically using `predict`) or do you want to estimate two models (maybe with the same formula) on two samples and look at some performance measure (e.g. loglikelihood, BIC...) ? This does not bring the same answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site. @linog raises a valid point. You may also want to consider fitting a single model on both populations, with a variable for population and perhaps interactions with other explanatory variables. If you add to your question what the goal of this comparison is, one might conclude which method is best. You can edit your question using the button below it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for an interaction term and a chunk test.

For two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ in each regression, the math is as follows; extending to more than just two variables is straightforward. Let $g(p) = \log\left(\dfrac{p}{1 - p}\right)$. Let $x_3$ be an indicator variable that takes $0$ for one group and $1$ for the other.

$$
g\left(\mathbb E\left[y_i\right]\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i1} + \beta_2x_{i2} + \beta_3x_{i3} +
\beta_4x_{i1} x_{i3} + \beta_5x_{i2} x_{i3}
$$

The model includes the original two features, an indicator variable for the group, and interactions between the group indicator and the original two variables.

Nested within such a model, by setting $\beta_3=\beta_4=\beta_5=0$, is the following model that you would have used for each group separately.

$$
g\left(\mathbb E\left[y_i\right]\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i1} + \beta_2x_{i2} + 
$$

You can fit the above model to each group, or you can fit the first model to both groups simultaneously. Then the $x_3$ variable acts like an on/off switch, showing how the regression parameters differ between the two groups.

To test if the groups differ in slope, test $\beta_3=0$. To test if the groups differ in $x_1$, test $\beta_4=0$. To test if the groups differ in $x_2$, test $\beta_5=0$. You also can test $\beta_3=\beta_4=\beta_5=0$ to see if the groups differ in their regressions at all. This testing is no different from any other testing of logistic regressions.

Below, I demonstrate how to do this in `R`. The final line of `lmtest::lrtest` uses a likelihood ratio test of nested models to calculate a p-value, either for one coefficient (giving the difference between the parameters for each group regressed separately) or for the three coefficients involving $x_3$ (testing if group membership affects the regression, what I have learned to call a [chunk test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests)).

```r
library(lmtest)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
x1 <- runif(N, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(N, 0, 1)
x3 <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
z <- x1 - x2 + x3 - x1*x3 + x2*x3
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)
L_full <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x3 + x2:x3, family = binomial)
L0 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial)
L4 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x3)
L5 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x2:x3)
L3 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
lmtest::lrtest(L0, L_full) # I get p = 0.00181 for the full chunk test
lmtest::lrtest(L0, L4) # I get p = 0.03512 for testing beta 4
lmtest::lrtest(L0, L5) # I get p = 0.9272 for testing beta 5
lmtest::lrtest(L0, L3) # I get p = 0.5902 for testing beta 3
```