# Seeking textbook reference for 2 way chi square tests for main effects and interaction

Tags: chi-squared-test, references, spss

I seek a textbook example of the application of chi square tests for main effects and interaction for categorical data, as in a 2x6 table.  I plan to use this to help me be sure I can correctly use CTABLES in SPSS.

Comment: I’ve made an assumption that you know how to F-test analogously in the case of linear regression. Please say if that part is unclear, because my answer will not make sense until that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

A $\chi^2$ test is a score test of nested (multinomial) logistic regression models, one of which just has an intercept and the other of which has a categorical predictor (much like ANOVA is a Wald test of nested linear regression models).

Consequently, if you want to extend this to something like two-way ANOVA with an interaction, you would do a (multinomial) logistic regression with multiple predictors. Then test the parameters with score tests, or [“chunk” test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests) to test multiple parameters at once (probably what you want if you have multiple levels in your factor variables).

[R has a package that will do the score test for you](https://rdrr.io/cran/mlogit/man/scoretest.html) if you know which regression models to pass in (totally analogous to F-testing nested models on linear regression). If you use another software, it likely has analogous functions.

**References**

Agresti, Alan. Foundations of linear and generalized linear models. John Wiley & Sons, 2015.

Agresti, Alan. Categorical data analysis. John Wiley & Sons, 2003.

Comment: My understanding of ANOVA is that there are estimates of variance due to main effects and interaction effect(s) and associated error variances used to test these effects.  I am unfamiliar with "nested (multinomial) logistic regression models".  Additional explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: @JoelW. Let's start with this: if you had to do two-way testing with interactions for a linear model, how would you do it? ("I don't know," is an acceptable answer.)

Comment: I would use SPSS to run a 2 way ANOVA, specifying which independent variables is random or fixed.  I would look at the table that shows mean squares, degrees of freedom, and significance values for main effects and interaction effects to see which are significant.  I would inspect plots of the means.  I would also look at the effect sizes for these effects.  I may look further, but this is where I would start.

Comment: Hmm. You asked me a question and I responded but I have yet to hear back from you. Why?

Comment: @JoelW. I can’t comment on SPSS, but the R package I linked will do whatever “chunk” test you want. (Remember that ANOVA is one kind of chunk test.)

Comment: Do you know of a textbook that uses and describes the approach you mention? Or, perhaps, a journal article?

Comment: @JoelW. Agresti, Alan. Foundations of linear and generalized linear models. John Wiley & Sons, 2015. I think the third chapter is when Agresti gets into Wald, likelihood ratio, and score tests of nested regression models.

Comment: I see he also wrote "An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis" which has a section on 3 way tables. TY

Comment: @JoelW. Did this answer your question? Perhaps you could consider accepting the answer and awarding the bounty to signal to others that this is helpful.