# How can I find out if an interaction between one categorical variable and one continuous variable has an effect on another continuous variable?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, ancova

First, I know just little about programming and statistics.
For this assignment I got a table with gene expression values (continuous data) for 3 environments (1, 2, 3 so categorical data) with temperature values (continuous data). It looks like this but there are about 50 genotype and temperature values for each type of environment:

| genotype | environment | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11.3528 | 1 | 30.7284 |
| 7.9493 | 1 | 23.4623 |
| 14.3437 | 2 | 25.3662 |
| 11.4799 | 2 | 22.2941 |
| 15.1744 | 3 | 25.0112 |
| 8.6173 | 3 | 17.9490 |

Now I have to proof if one of the following statements is true:

The null hypothesis - *The interaction between temperature and environment has no effect on gene expression.*

The alternative hypothesis - *The interaction between temperature and environment has an effect on gene expression.*

What should I do? I've heard someone solved it with emmeans() but I don't know anything about it.

I've already done the ANCOVA test which resulted in this:

[image]

Does it make sense?

Comment: I am not sure of what you're asking, in part because you say "dataset" where I think you mean "variable". But if you really mean "interaction," the model you fitted does not include the interaction. I'd suggest, for starters, fitting the model `aov(geneexpression ~ environment * temp, data = x)` which will add the interaction term `environment:temp`. I also think that type II is more appropriate than type III, as well as being less problematic in its implementation.

Comment: Oops, I also notice that you have`environment` in there as a numeric predictor. You should change `x$environment <- factor(x$environment)` -- unless you think environment 3 is 1.5 times as much as environment 2.

Comment: it does make more sense now! thank you very much! maybe I will probably have more questions but we will see

Answer (score 0):

I would test this by running a regression with the predictors being the environment categorical variable on its own, the continuous temperature variable on its own, and an interaction between the two variables. Then I would test the coefficient on the interaction. However, this is complicated by the fact that your categorical variable has three levels, so there is not just one interaction term. Your regression winds up being something like this.

$$
\mathbb E[Y\vert X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{\text{temp}} + \beta_2 x_{\text{env2}} + \beta_3 x_{\text{env3}} + \beta_4x_{\text{temp}}x_{\text{env2}} + \beta_5x_{\text{temp}}x_{\text{env3}}
$$

As is typical of a regression with categorical variables, one of the categories (here, environment 1) is subsumed by the intercept $\beta_0$.

Then, I would jointly test the $\beta_4$ and $\beta_5$ coefficients to see if either is nonzero. I have gotten into calling this a [chunk test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests) because the test is of an entire chunk of coefficients instead of just one. A typical test in this situation would be to consider the above model to be the full model and the model below that drops the interactions to be the reduced model, and then perform an F-test.

$$
\mathbb E[Y\vert X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{\text{temp}} + \beta_2 x_{\text{env2}} + \beta_3 x_{\text{env3}} 
$$

In software, you could execute this as follows.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
x1 <- runif(N, 0, 1)
x2 <- as.factor(sample(c(1, 2, 3), N, replace = T))
y <- 2*x1 + rnorm(N)
model_full <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2)
model_reduced <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
anova(model_reduced, model_full)
```

I get a p-value of `0.1304` from the `anova` line, which is consistent with the fact that my simulated data made no use of the interaction (or even of the categorical `x2` variable).

**EDIT**

The math is as follows. Define $SSR_0$ to be the sum of squared residuals for the reduced model, $SSR_1$ to be the sum of squared residuals for the full model, $n$ to be the sample size, $p_0=4$ to be the number of coefficients in the reduced model, and $p_1=6$ to be the number of coefficients in the full model. Then:

$$
\dfrac{
\left(
SSR_0 - SSR_1
\right)
/
\left(
p_1 - p_0
\right)
}{
\left(
SSR_1
\right)
/
\left(
n - p_1
\right)
}
=F\sim F_{p_1 - p_0, \space n - p_1}
$$

A reference is on page 89 of Agresti (2015).

Then this "F-statistic" is compared to the F-distribution with $p_1 - p_0$ and $n - p_1$ degrees of freedom to calculate a p-value. You want the probability above this calculated $F$.

**REFERENCE**

Agresti, Alan. Foundations of linear and generalized linear models. John Wiley & Sons, 2015.