# How to run a t-test in R with multiple variables

Tags: r, t-test

I have this data frame (reproducible):

```
## structure(list(age = c(62.84998, 60.33899, 52.74698, 42.38498
## ), death = c(0, 1, 1, 1), sex = c("male", "female", "female", 
## "female"), hospdead = c(0, 1, 0, 0), slos = c(5, 4, 17, 3), d.time = c(2029, 
## 4, 47, 133), dzgroup = c("Lung Cancer", "Cirrhosis", "Cirrhosis", 
## "Lung Cancer"), dzclass = c("Cancer", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", 
## "Cancer"), num.co = c(0, 2, 2, 2), edu = c(11, 12, 12, 11), income = c("$11-$25k", 
## "$11-$25k", "under $11k", "under $11k"), scoma = c(0, 44, 0, 
## 0), charges = c(9715, 34496, 41094, 3075), totcst = c(NA_real_, 
## NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), totmcst = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
## NA_real_, NA_real_), avtisst = c(7, 29, 13, 7), race = c("other", 
## "white", "white", "white"), sps = c(33.8984375, 52.6953125, 20.5, 
## 20.0976562), aps = c(20, 74, 45, 19), surv2m = c(0.262939453, 
## 0.0009999275, 0.790893555, 0.698974609), surv6m = c(0.0369949341, 
## 0, 0.664916992, 0.411987305), hday = c(1, 3, 4, 1), diabetes = c(0, 
## 0, 0, 0), dementia = c(0, 0, 0, 0), ca = c("metastatic", "no", 
## "no", "metastatic"), prg2m = c(0.5, 0, 0.75, 0.899999619), prg6m = c(0.25, 
## 0, 0.5, 0.5), dnr = c("no dnr", NA, "no dnr", "no dnr"), dnrday = c(5, 
## NA, 17, 3), meanbp = c(97, 43, 70, 75), wblc = c(6, 17.0976562, 
## 8.5, 9.09960938), hrt = c(69, 112, 88, 88), resp = c(22, 34, 
## 28, 32), temp = c(36, 34.59375, 37.39844, 35), pafi = c(388, 
## 98, 231.65625, NA), alb = c(1.7998047, NA, NA, NA), bili = c(0.19998169, 
## NA, 2.19970703, NA), crea = c(1.19995117, 5.5, 2, 0.79992676), 
##     sod = c(141, 132, 134, 139), ph = c(7.459961, 7.25, 7.459961, 
##     NA), glucose = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
##     bun = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), urine = c(NA_real_, 
##     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), adlp = c(7, NA, 1, 0), adls = c(7, 
##     1, 0, 0), sfdm2 = c(NA, "<2 mo. follow-up", "<2 mo. follow-up", 
##     "no(M2 and SIP pres)"), adlsc = c(7, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
## 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have also made a graph of the SUPPORT day 3 physiology score (sps) grouped by the primary disease class (dzclass) with a DataFrame name of SB_xlsx.

```
SB_xlsx = SB_xlsx[!is.na(SB_xlsx$sps), ]
ggplot(SB_xlsx, aes(x=dzclass, y=sps)) + geom_boxplot() + ggtitle("Box Plot - sps by Primary Disease Class") + xlab("Disease Class") + ylab("sps")
```

Now I want to test whether the population mean SUPPORT day 3 physiology scores differ between the primary disease classes. I figured I would do this with a t-test in R, but I'm not sure how to set this one up. This is the beginning of the code I have.

```
t.test(x=SB_xlsx$dzclass, y=SB_xlsx$sps, mu=diff.mu, var_equal=TRUE, conf_level=1-alpha, alternative=
'two.sided')
```

However, this doesn't work since there are multiple disease classes. How would I go about setting up this t.test?

Comment: A t-test is between two sets of values. Do you mean performing all pairs of t-tests? If so, is that preferable to other approaches such as ANOVA/GLM?

Comment: Is your question primarily about programming t-tests in R?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a ["chunk test"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests) of nested models?

Comment: You question seems to be how to run multiple t-tests and so is more appropriate for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to test whether the population mean of the continuous variable `sps` differs across the groups defined by the categorical variable `dzclass`, which has more than two categories. Moreover, you have cross-sectional data where each row represents one individual.

In this setting, with more than two groups, a t-test is not applicable, instead one normally uses [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance).

Since your sample dataset doesn't include so many rows and only two groups, I use the following dataset to illustrate:

```
library("stats")
library("ggplot2")

n = 1000
age = runif(n, 30, 70)
sex = sample(c("male", "female"), n, replace = TRUE)
race = sample(c("white", "black", "other"), n, replace = TRUE)
dzclass = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), n, replace = TRUE)

sps = age + 10 * as.numeric(as.factor(sex)) +
      10 * as.numeric(as.factor(race)) +
      as.numeric(as.factor(dzclass)) + rnorm(n, sd=10)

d = data.frame(sps, dzclass, age, sex, race)

ggplot(d, aes(x=as.factor(dzclass), y=sps)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    ggtitle("Box Plot - sps by Primary Disease Class") +
    xlab("Disease Class") +
    ylab("sps")
```

To test whether the group-`dzclass`-means of `sps` differ one can uses the p-values returned here:

```
fit = aov(sps ~ dzclass, data=d)
summary(fit)
```

However, the estimates of the population means might be biased due to selection. Since your data seems to contain several potential useful control variables, you can likely do better. Even if there is no selection, including control variables typically increases the precision of your estimates. In the following example I'm assuming that a linear model is a good fit for your data (if not consider transformations or non-linear models). A better way to test whether the group means differ might then be to run ANOVA with controls (or equivalently an F-test for the group coefficients in a linear regression) by using the p-values returned in the last step here:

```
fit1 = lm(sps ~ factor(dzclass) + age + factor(sex) + factor(race), data=d)
summary(fit1)

fit2 = lm(sps ~ age + factor(sex) + factor(race), data=d)
summary(fit2)

anova(fit1, fit2)
```

Of course you should adapt the control variables to something that makes sense with your data.

Finally, if you really want to, you could run pairwise t-tests while adjusting for multiple testing (this is approximative only):

```
pairwise.t.test(d$sps, d$dzclass, p.adjust.method="holm")
```

where setting `p.adjust.method="none"` gives unadjusted t-tests.

Another way to just run the standard pairwise t-tests is:

```
mu.diff = 0
alpha = 0.05
combs = combn(unique(d$dzclass), 2)

for (s in 1:ncol(combs)) {
  i = combs[1, s]
  j = combs[2, s]
  
  tt = t.test(sps ~ dzclass, mu=mu.diff, var_equal=FALSE, 
              conf_level=1-alpha, alternative='two.sided', 
              data=d[d$dzclass == i | d$dzclass == j, ])
  print(tt)
}
```

Comment: I think this method works well, but I am having an error "error in eval(m$data, parent.frame()) : object 'dzclass' not found". I'm not sure as to why this is, since that is a column in my dataset.

Comment: Ok, I edited the code so that it should work now if you call your dataframe `d = SB_xlsx` or replace the mentions of `d` with `SB_xlsx`.