# What does F-statistic tell us in regression analysis?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

What does F-statistic tell us in regression analysis? also, can someone explain to me the logic behind its formula, please?

Comment: [Also worth mentioning are “chunk tests”](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests), though I concede that the topic is more advanced.