# ANCOVA with binary covariate

Tags: anova, binary-data, continuous-data, ancova

I am looking to run an ANCOVA with continuous outcome variable, looking at the effect of a categorical variable (race/ethnicity) and controlling for a binary covariate (treatment condition, values 0 or 1). So:

1. Can ANCOVA be used with a binary (0, 1) covariate? It seems no based on what I'm reading, but I wanted to affirm.
2. If not, what analysis should be used? (If regression, please say so - I am usually a regression user but am looking to integrate ANCOVA based on a reviewer comments, and this is less my wheelhouse)

Comment: Usually, an ANCOVA is a multiple linear regression with both continuous and categorical predictors. As such, it's no problem to include a binary predictor. From your description, you don't seem to have a continuous predictor. Could you expand on your situation and variables please?

Answer (score 2):

The classical ANCOVA tends to refer to using a continuous covariate. In that sense, no, you cannot run ANCOVA without a continuous covariate. However, absolutely zero theory changes when it comes to running the test of the other variable. ANCOVA is just a term used to describe a common regression hypothesis test, but regression works in much more generality.

Whether or not it is wise to call this test ANCOVA is not clear to me, but the test you would run is totally legitimate: just an F-test of a factor variable with some other variable included in the regression model but not the test.

This is one example of what I have gotten into the habit of calling a [“chunk test”](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests).

Answer (score 0):

ANOVA, ANCOVA, and regression are all the same model:

$Y = XB + e$

But the term "regression" is used much more generally. You can do it with independent variables that are binary, multinomial, or continuous. ANOVA is the term used when you have only categorical variables. ANCOVA when you have one "covariate" that is continuous. I put "covariate" in parentheses because the model doesn't know the difference between an independent variable and a covariate -- that's on you.

The output from the typical ANOVA or ANCOVA often looks different, but that's just a matter of which things are output in what order and format, the results are really the same.

Your reviewer's comments don't really make sense. And, since you posted this 8 months ago, it's probably no longer an issue in this particular case.