# What is nonlinear p-value in Wald Statistics?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, p-value, nonlinear-regression

I am running a binary logistic regression with splines in R (using the `rms` package). I do not know what p-value I can report in an article. Should it be the nonlinear p-value or the main p-value?

```r
> knots1
[1] 284.00 314.55 366.15 640.00
> knots2
[1]  19.00  24.85  45.90 109.00
> knots3
[1]  32 104 139
...
model2 <-  lrm(formula = P_A ~ rcs(HEIGHT, knots1) + 
         rcs(CEILING, knots2) + rcs(H_CEILING, knots3) + 
         rcs(BED_L, knots4) + BED_W + rcs(TREE_DIST, knots6) + 
         rcs(BUILD_DIST, knots7) + GREEN_DIST + NEST_DIST + 
         DETECT, data=data, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: What is that `model2`? Could you please post the entire line where you call something like `model2 <- rms::ols(y~…)`? // As far as what you want to report in your article, what are you testing?

Comment: I want to run a binary logistic regression to understanding (modeling) factors affecting nest-site selection in a bird species. I have Presence/Absence data and 13 predictors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to rely on what I have seen Harrell refer to as a [chunk test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests).

Your “Height” p-value seems to be the p-value coming from a Wald test of two nested models. The full model is the model2 you use. The reduced model is the model that lacks “height” and the spline features derived from the “height” feature. This is a test of if height has any relationship with the outcome, linear or nonlinear.

Then the “nonlinear” p-value under “height” does the same kind of chunk test but keeps the linear “height” feature in the reduced model. This is a test of if height has a nonlinear relationship with the outcome.

Ditto for the other variables you model with splines.

The “total nonlinear” p-value comes from a chunk test of all of the spline features. The full model is the same full model as always, and the reduced model only uses linear features.

Finally, the total p-value comes from testing the entire model against a reduced model that only has an intercept.

As far as what to report in your article, you probably should report all of the p-values and give context for what they mean, though I have my doubts about how well this kind of modeling helps address the question you have about what affects where birds nest. Such questions typically require more delicate handling.

**EDIT**

I'm not getting Wald testing to work in `R`, but doing likelihood ratio tests (should give about the same answer as Wald testing) shows this stance to be about right.

```
library(lmtest)
library(rms)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
x1 <- runif(N, 0, 10) # Make up feature 1
x2 <- runif(N, 0, 10) # Make up feature 2
y <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5) # Make up a binary outcome
L_full <- rms::lrm(y ~ rcs(x1, 5) + rcs(x2, 7)) # Fit full model in `rms`
G_full <- glm(y ~ rcs(x1, 5) + rcs(x2, 7), family = binomial) # Fit full GLM
G_linear_1 <- glm(y ~ x1 + rcs(x2, 7), family = binomial) # Fit with linear x1
G_linear_2 <- glm(y ~ x2 + rcs(x1, 5), family = binomial)  # Fit with linear x2
G_no_x1 <- glm(y ~ rcs(x2, 7), family = binomial) # Fit without x1 at all
G_no_x2 <- glm(y ~ rcs(x1, 5), family = binomial) # Fit without x2 at all
G_all_linear <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial) # Fit only linear features
G_null <- glm(y ~ 1, family = binomial) # Fit intercept-only model
lmtest::lrtest(G_no_x1, G_full) # Test x1 overall
lmtest::lrtest(G_linear_1, G_full) # Test the nonlinear x1 splines
lmtest::lrtest(G_no_x2, G_full) # Test x2 overall
lmtest::lrtest(G_linear_2, G_full) # Test the nonlinear x2 splines
lmtest::lrtest(G_all_linear, G_full) # Test all nonlinear splines
lmtest::lrtest(G_null, G_full) # Test all features
anova(L_full)

################################################################################
#
# Output
#
################################################################################

> lmtest::lrtest(G_no_x1, G_full) # Test x1 overall
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: y ~ rcs(x2, 7)
Model 2: y ~ rcs(x1, 5) + rcs(x2, 7)
#Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1   7 -689.26                     
2  11 -685.61  4 7.2961      0.121
> lmtest::lrtest(G_linear_1, G_full) # Test the nonlinear x1 splines
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: y ~ x1 + rcs(x2, 7)
Model 2: y ~ rcs(x1, 5) + rcs(x2, 7)
#Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
1   8 -689.25                       
2  11 -685.61  3 7.2713    0.06374 .
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> lmtest::lrtest(G_no_x2, G_full) # Test x2 overall
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: y ~ rcs(x1, 5)
Model 2: y ~ rcs(x1, 5) + rcs(x2, 7)
#Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1   5 -689.69                     
2  11 -685.61  6 8.1521     0.2272
> lmtest::lrtest(G_linear_2, G_full) # Test the nonlinear x2 splines
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: y ~ x2 + rcs(x1, 5)
Model 2: y ~ rcs(x1, 5) + rcs(x2, 7)
#Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1   6 -689.54                     
2  11 -685.61  5 7.8583     0.1642
> lmtest::lrtest(G_all_linear, G_full) # Test all nonlinear splines
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: y ~ x1 + x2
Model 2: y ~ rcs(x1, 5) + rcs(x2, 7)
#Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
1   3 -692.98                       
2  11 -685.61  8 14.729    0.06464 .
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> lmtest::lrtest(G_null, G_full) # Test all features
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: y ~ 1
Model 2: y ~ rcs(x1, 5) + rcs(x2, 7)
#Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1   1 -693.15                     
2  11 -685.61 10 15.062     0.1298
> anova(L_full)
Wald Statistics          Response: y 

Factor          Chi-Square d.f. P     
x1               7.20       4   0.1259
Nonlinear       7.18       3   0.0665
x2               8.07       6   0.2333
Nonlinear       7.78       5   0.1685
TOTAL NONLINEAR 14.39       8   0.0721
TOTAL           14.70      10   0.1434
```

When you compare the degrees of freedom in the tests and the p-values, the tests with corresponding degrees of freedom have about the same p-value.

$$
df = 4\implies 0.121\text{ vs }0.1259\\
df = 3\implies 0.06374\text{ vs }0.0665\\
df = 6\implies 0.2272\text{ vs }0.2333\\
df = 5\implies 0.1642\text{ vs }0.1685\\
df = 8\implies 0.06464\text{ vs }0.0721\\
df = 10\implies 0.1298\text{ vs }0.1434\\
$$

Comment: Thank you so much.