# Significance test of an increase in adjusted R-squared between two models

Tags: regression, r-squared, stepwise-regression

I found two papers that provide their results showing the significance of an increase in adjusted R-squared between two models statistically, with p-values, to show the improvement after adding a few more explanatory variables.

One paper: https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/10.1287/mnsc.1050.0366
The other paper: https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/msom.2016.0597

I am interested in replicating those two studies, but I cannot find what exact test the significance of an increase in adjusted R-squared between two models. Can I get some insights about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a [chunk test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27429/247274) of those added variables. If you have a significant contribution by that combination of variables in terms of improving square loss (which adjusted $R^2$ measures, penalizing your model for its parameter count), that is equivalent to that combination of variables being significant. The test literally compares the performance of two models.

The usual F-test compares your model to a baseline model that only has an intercept, penalizing your model for being more complicated. This usual F-test can be written in terms of adjusted $R^2$. A chunk test compares the performance of your model to a baseline that contains some subset of the variables, rather than comparing to the intercept-only baseline.

Comment: Thank you very much! The link you attached is very helpful.