# Difference between Fixed Effects predictor Value and ggeffects predicted values

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have generated a linear mixed model with a random intercept with

`model <- lme(q0 ~ DominancePattern + PC1 + Region + pH + WT + DominancePattern:PC1 + DominancePattern:pH + PC1:pH + pH:WT + Region:WT + pH:Region + PC1:Region + PC1:WT, random = ~1|LocalityShort, data = subplots, method = "REML")`

If I run `summary(model)` I get the following output,

```
> summary(model)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: subplots 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  5918.487 6020.653 -2940.244

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | LocalityShort
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.232107 1.455671

Fixed effects:  q0 ~ DominancePattern + PC1 + Region + pH + WT + DominancePattern:PC1 +      DominancePattern:pH + PC1:pH + pH:WT + Region:WT + pH:Region +      PC1:Region + PC1:WT 
                            Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)              6.599751 1.3939377 1586  4.734609  0.0000
DominancePatternCod     -1.997145 0.8257099 1586 -2.418701  0.0157
DominancePatternSph     -2.903818 0.9216193 1586 -3.150778  0.0017
PC1                     -4.654946 1.7542579   13 -2.653513  0.0199
RegionPyrenees          -3.696524 1.7666995   13 -2.092333  0.0566
pH                      -0.285197 0.2171754 1586 -1.313210  0.1893
WTW                     -1.291710 1.0342973 1586 -1.248877  0.2119
DominancePatternCod:PC1 -0.533856 0.1431446 1586 -3.729487  0.0002
DominancePatternSph:PC1  0.436505 0.1489416 1586  2.930710  0.0034
DominancePatternCod:pH   0.455349 0.1412465 1586  3.223788  0.0013
DominancePatternSph:pH   0.572082 0.1599060 1586  3.577614  0.0004
PC1:pH                   0.733259 0.2605009 1586  2.814803  0.0049
pH:WTW                   0.299932 0.1679071 1586  1.786299  0.0742
RegionPyrenees:WTW      -0.483324 0.2032903 1586 -2.377508  0.0175
RegionPyrenees:pH        0.384239 0.2900847 1586  1.324575  0.1855
PC1:RegionPyrenees       1.066021 1.0283247   13  1.036658  0.3188
PC1:WTW                 -0.123338 0.1317932 1586 -0.935847  0.3495
 Correlation: 
                        (Intr) DmnnPC DmnnPS PC1    RgnPyr pH     WTW    DPC:PC DPS:PC DmPC:H DmPS:H PC1:pH pH:WTW
DominancePatternCod     -0.188                                                                                    
DominancePatternSph     -0.179  0.407                                                                             
PC1                     -0.217 -0.018  0.171                                                                      
RegionPyrenees          -0.752 -0.064  0.012  0.344                                                               
pH                      -0.948  0.207  0.198  0.175  0.704                                                        
WTW                     -0.287  0.043  0.024 -0.099  0.079  0.302                                                 
DominancePatternCod:PC1 -0.035  0.168  0.085  0.088  0.064  0.037  0.056                                          
DominancePatternSph:PC1 -0.054  0.048  0.212 -0.130  0.115  0.060  0.072  0.465                                   
DominancePatternCod:pH   0.175 -0.994 -0.400  0.036  0.081 -0.197 -0.035 -0.165 -0.047                            
DominancePatternSph:pH   0.147 -0.403 -0.994 -0.144  0.021 -0.168 -0.033 -0.081 -0.215  0.401                     
PC1:pH                   0.197  0.014 -0.199 -0.893 -0.353 -0.199  0.107 -0.144  0.099 -0.034  0.169              
pH:WTW                   0.309 -0.037 -0.025  0.093 -0.099 -0.328 -0.995 -0.055 -0.073  0.028  0.033 -0.099       
RegionPyrenees:WTW       0.033 -0.015  0.044  0.186  0.205 -0.019 -0.619  0.014  0.026  0.018 -0.028 -0.217  0.566
RegionPyrenees:pH        0.683  0.063 -0.025 -0.343 -0.931 -0.712 -0.056 -0.077 -0.135 -0.081 -0.010  0.391  0.079
PC1:RegionPyrenees       0.112  0.003 -0.032 -0.524 -0.084 -0.039  0.025 -0.029  0.025 -0.008  0.026  0.207 -0.023
PC1:WTW                 -0.086  0.030  0.093  0.362  0.155  0.094 -0.012  0.078 -0.032 -0.020 -0.080 -0.440 -0.008
                        RP:WTW RgnP:H PC1:RP
DominancePatternCod                         
DominancePatternSph                         
PC1                                         
RegionPyrenees                              
pH                                          
WTW                                         
DominancePatternCod:PC1                     
DominancePatternSph:PC1                     
DominancePatternCod:pH                      
DominancePatternSph:pH                      
PC1:pH                                      
pH:WTW                                      
RegionPyrenees:WTW                          
RegionPyrenees:pH       -0.280              
PC1:RegionPyrenees      -0.044  0.076       
PC1:WTW                  0.268 -0.186 -0.091

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.9151458 -0.6516760 -0.0709071  0.5767404  4.4763677 

Number of Observations: 1616
Number of Groups: 17
```

If I look at the Fixed Effects section of the output I can see several predictors with apparent significance. They naturally have a corresponding "Value" column, which I interpret as "if I modify one unit of this predictor, my `q0` output will be modified by such value".
At the same time, there is a Random Effects section, both for the random intercept and for the uncontrolled error, the standard deviation of which I interpret as how much the values of `q0` vary among the levels of LocalityShort or among some "uncontrolled" variability or error.

Thus, if I look at some predictor's value, like `PC1`, despite having an estimated fixed effect of `-4.65`, when I run
`ggeffect` over this variable, the predicted values of `q0` barely vary `0.02` for every unit of `PC1`,

```
> ggeffect(model, c("PC1"), type = "random")
  PC1 | Predicted |       95% CI
--------------------------------
-1.39 |      4.75 | [3.18, 6.33]
-0.79 |      4.74 | [3.69, 5.78]
-0.29 |      4.73 | [4.02, 5.44]
-0.19 |      4.72 | [4.05, 5.39]
 0.17 |      4.71 | [4.08, 5.35]
 0.22 |      4.71 | [4.07, 5.36]
 0.37 |      4.71 | [4.01, 5.41]
 1.06 |      4.69 | [3.50, 5.88]
```

If I understand correclty, this must be because now `ggeffect` is taking into account the variability of my random intercept and of the error.

If so, then, how should I analyse the results of `summary(model)`, considering the Values for the Fixed Effects are clearly not a good representation of their *actual* effect on the response variable. I still believe the indicated p-values must be relatively consistent, but what about the actual effect of the variables? Can I even trust their sign in the Fixed Effects section?

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the parameter estimate for PC1 in the `lmer` model summary is conditional any variables that PC1 is interacted with. In this case, you interacted PC1 with DominancePatternCod and WTW. Accordingly the PCI coefficient represents the association between the outcome and PC1 when DominancePatternCod and WTW are equal to 0. That maybe a sensible situation or it may not be, depending on whether the two variables in question have meaningful 0 values. Otherwise, it may be outside their range and represent something nonsensical. You can deal with this in a principled manner by centering all the variables involved in interactions. People often choose to center such variables around their grand mean in the sample. When that is done, a value of 0 are their sample mean.

You can trust the estimates from the lmer summary to the degree that you trust your model as representing a good approximation of the data generating process for your outcome. They are technically correct given the model you specified and under the assumptions of mixed effects models.

As to `ggeffects`, it is giving you the [marginal effect](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_marginal_effects.html) (aka, prediction) for the effect of PC1 based on your model. It does so holding the other variables in the model at their [mean value](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/ggeffects.html). Thus it is giving you the predicted q0 value for each value of PC1 when all other predictors in the model are held constant at their means.

You could take this a step further to help you understand how PC1 modifies the association between the outcome and DominancePatternCod and WTW by using `ggpredict` to get marginal predictions for the combination of values represented in the interaction.

```
domPC <- ggpredict(model, terms = c("PC1", "DominancePatternCod")
WTWPC <- ggpredict(model, terms = c("PC1", "WTW")
```

When you use the ggpredict option `type = "random"`, you are simply having ggpredict include the uncertainty from the random effect when making predictions. This leads to much larger confidence intervals than when you leave that out. Most people leave it out, in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

As Erik Ruzek points out in another answer (+1), the `PC1` coefficient is the value when all the predictors with which it interacts have values of 0: all of `pH`, `DominancePattern`, `Region`, and `WT`. In the default treatment coding used by R, those last 3 categorical predictors have values of 0 when they are at their reference levels.

The concept of a "mean value" is a little difficult for your 3 categorical predictors. It might be best to interpret that the way that this [`ggeffects` vignette](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/technical_differencepredictemmeans.html) explains:

> `ggemmeans()` - like `ggeffect()` - averages over the proportions of the categories of factors.

That is why you have small differences in `Predicted` over the range of `PC1` values that you provided despite the apparently large `PC1` coefficient. As the answer from Erik Ruzek notes, the `type="random"` argument only affects the widths of the confidence intervals, not the point estimates.

If you want to know whether `PC1` has a significant association with outcome, use the `anova.lme()` function on your `model`, with a `Terms` argument specifying *all* coefficients (individual and interaction) that involve `PC1`. That provides a Wald ["chunk test"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27429/28500) evaluating the joint null hypothesis that all those coefficients have values of 0.